# How can I make the window fonts bolder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, text-formatting

Is there a way in Windows 7 to make fonts on windows **stronger**?

I am trying to help someone figure out how to make text easier to read. I have already adjusted the text DPI, used ease of access options, the resolution, and advanced appearance options, but you can not select 'window' in the drop down and change any font properties, just colors.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "Window Color and Appearence" select the element type you want to change, and click the "B" next to font size/color.

You can also try a bolder typeface.

[image]

Comment: It doesnt solve the problem because all fonts inside system windows, tabs titles, labels, descriptions, button fonts, etc. remain unchanged and are very thin.

Comment: @TomeeNS I believe at the time I posted this it worked for me, and apparently it worked for Jeff too as he Accepted the answer.  It sounds like you are affected by an additional or different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Right click -> Personalize -> Window Color

Selects the parts you want to adjust, make them bold, or make the font bigger.

That will do at least part of the job.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on desktop
2. Click on Personalize
3. Click on Window Color
4. (Aero theme only) Click on Advance Appearance Settings
5. Select text you want to be **bold**.
6. Click OK.
7. Save changes and exit.

Side note: If the item is already bold'd, you can try using another font that is "extra bold".